# React Native Fast Refresh Not Working Without sudo npm start

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, watchman, metro-bundler

My react native project cannot use React Native fast refresh feature without `sudo npm start`

If i just run `npm start` ios simulator cannot update when i save js file from vscode.

How can i solve this issue? Packager does not respond without hard reload (cmd + r)

output of `watchman watch-list`

```
{
    "version": "4.9.0",
    "roots": [
        "/path/to/project-root",
        
    ]
}
```

package versions:

- npm : 6.14.9
- "react": "16.13.1",
- "react-native": "0.63.4",

What did i try?

- i uninstalled watchman, install again,
- clear npm cache, watchman cache, metro bundler cache 50 times.
- remove ./git/index.lock
- remove node_modules & install again
- remove whole project from computer and clone from git
- give full file access to watchman from macos settings
- `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/bin/npm`
- `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/bin/node`
- `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/lib/node_modules/`
- `sudo chown -R $(whoami /usr/local`
- create clean react native project and try on that

none of them worked for me. But if i run `sudo npm start` then `npm run-ios`, it works. But what did happen why npm stopped working without `sudo`

I did not change anything.

```
watchman --server-encoding=json --persistent log-level debug
```

with this command i can confirm watchman is working for my project. When i change a file and save, it's logging.

Also i tried `yarn run ios`

Comment: Could you please confirm for me your watchman runs when you start your packager?

Comment: Maybe this link could help you.
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar i updated my questions. watchman --server-encoding=json --persistent log-level debug is working and file changes trigger the log.

Comment: I faced same issue, switched to yarn instead of npm and hot reload started working again.

Comment: @KetanRamteke I also tried yarn and still i can not use fast refresh.

Comment: @hakiko, did you manage to find a solution?